# Counting pairwise combinations from many options in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-access, statistics

I have a large dataset of students and the classes they have taken. Each student has taken 12 to 18 of around 80 available classes. Using Excel (2013) I would like to find out, for any given pair of classes, how many students took both of them. I envisage a table with the 80 classes as both rows and columns, and then for each intersection I would see a count of how many students took that combination.

The data arrive as an Excel file with one row per student per class:

```
Student  Class
Smith    E101
Jones    E101
Parker   E101
Brown    E102
Green    E102
Smith    E201
Jones    E202
Parker   E201
Brown    E202
Green    E203
...
```

Envisaged output:

```
      E101  E102  E201  E202  E203  ...
E101        0     2     1     0
E102  0           0     1     1    
E201  2     0           0     0
E202  1     1     0           0
E203  0     1     0     0
...
```

(Obviously I only need a diagonal half of the above, as the other half mirrors it.)

I've used a pivot table to get the data into a table with students as rows, and all possible classes as columns, showing a 1 where a student took a given class.

```
        E101  E102  E201  E202  E203  ...
Smith   1           1           
Jones   1                 1         
Parker  1           1          
Brown         1           1     
Green         1                 1
...
```

But I'm then stuck on how to proceed, with as little manual intervention as possible, to my desired output.

Can anyone suggest a way to achieve the output I need in Excel? I've done fairly extensive searching but haven't found anything.

Or should I be looking to other software?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm not using any scripts/code. I have got as far as using a pivot table, as above, to go from a flat list to a crosstabulation of student and class. I now do not know whether there is a way of achieving what I want (as per the post) in Excel, despite fairly extensive searching. My question is therefore can I obtain that information within Excel, and if so, how? I don't mean to be obtuse but I don't see what is wrong with my question and would welcome more explanation on that. I am not asking for code, but suggestions of approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite simple to do in Excel with a formula that operates on your pivot table.

With the two tables set up like this

[image: Worksheet Screenshot showing Tables and Formula]

enter the following formula in `J2` and ctrl-enter/copy-paste/fill-down&right/auto-fill into the rest of the table's cells:

```dart
=
IF(
  J$1=$I2,
  "",
  COUNTIFS(
    INDEX($A$1:$F$6,ROW($A$1:$F$6),MATCH(J$1,$A$1:$F$1,0)):INDEX($A$1:$F$6,1+ROWS($A$1:$F$6)-ROW($A$1:$F$6),MATCH(J$1,$A$1:$F$1,0)),
    1,
    INDEX($A$1:$F$6,ROW($A$1:$F$6),MATCH($I2,$A$1:$F$1,0)):INDEX($A$1:$F$6,1+ROWS($A$1:$F$6)-ROW($A$1:$F$6),MATCH($I2,$A$1:$F$1,0)),
    1
  )
)
```

**Explanation:**

The first argument of the `COUNTIFS()` function is the dynamically generated column of the pivot table corresponding to the column header of the output table. It's a little easier to understand if we look at the intermediate evaluated steps (for cell `L2`):

`INDEX($A$1:$F$6,ROW($A$1:$F$6),MATCH(L$1,$A$1:$F$1,0)):INDEX($A$1:$F$6,1+ROWS($A$1:$F$6)-ROW($A$1:$F$6),MATCH(L$1,$A$1:$F$1,0))`
→`INDEX($A$1:$F$6,1,MATCH("E201",$A$1:$F$1,0)):INDEX($A$1:$F$6,6,MATCH("E201",$A$1:$F$1,0))`
→`INDEX($A$1:$F$6,1,4):INDEX($A$1:$F$6,6,4)`
→`$D$1:$D$6`

(Note that the second arguments of each `INDEX()` are just the fully dynamic start and end rows, respectively, of the pivot table.)

Similarly for the third argument of the `COUNTIFS()` function, but this time the dynamically generated column of the pivot table corresponds to the *row* header of the output table. For cell `L2` it evaluates to `$B$1:$B$6`.

Thus the `COUNTIFS()` function in `L2` becomes

```dart
COUNTIFS($D$1:$D$6,1,$B$1:$B$6,1)
```

which is the standard way of counting the number of rows (students) where *both* columns contain a `1` (i.e. the student was enrolled in both classes).

The encapsulating `IF()` function is just there to ensure that the diagonal cells are blank.

Comment: Thank you @robinCTS ! Please accept huge apologies for the time it took to reply. I had some issues with logging in to StackExchange that meant I was not able to respond until now, but I did read and implement the solution. I simply adjusted the ranges for my own data and it works perfectly. I especially appreciate the detailed explanation of each element - it took some time to work through but I understand. I'm very grateful for your time!

Comment: @ermintrude75 Not a problem. Glad to help! I'm just sorry your question was initially closed and took so long to be re-opened.